# Gravity in pygame is crashing my program

Tags: python, loops, timer, pygame, gravity

So I am working on a side scrolling game in pygame, and I am trying to implement gravity.
The code I have now theoretically work, but the program just stops responding and I have close it. I don't even get any errors throw back at me to let me know what is wrong.

I used to have gravity working, but it only activated while no keys were pressed. If you held down the "jump button" (space bar) you would infinitely move upwards, and when you released it, you would finally start falling. 
So I changed my ideas and went about making gravity was with a loop inside a keydown event.
Inside the loop I add two variables, gravity and grav_time, and set a variable add_grav_time to True. While this is true and gravity is less than a number I make the character jump up. As soon as gravity is more than a certain number I make the character fall down. Then I reset gravity. I don't see any error with my code, so I don't know what the problem is.

```
import Level, pygame, sys
import time
pygame.init()
f=open("lvl1.txt")
lvldata=[]
for line in f:
    x=line.split()
    lvldata.append([int(v)for v in x]) 

size=1000,555
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.key.set_repeat(15,15)
lvl=Level.Level(lvldata,screen,size)
hero_img=pygame.image.load("hero.png")
herorect=pygame.Rect(lvl.spawn_x, lvl.spawn_y, 100, 100)
hero_position=[lvl.spawn_x, lvl.spawn_y]
velocity = [0,0]
face='R'
bkrd = pygame.image.load("bkrd2.png")
bkrdrect = bkrd.get_rect()
Gc=0
while True:
    Gc+=0.1
    if lvl.checkcollision(herorect):
        velocity=[0,0]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.QUIT]:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                if face=='R':
                    hero_img = pygame.transform.flip(hero_img, True, False)
                    face='L'
                if herorect.left>0:
                    hero_position[0]-=10
                else:
                    hero_position[0]=0

            if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                if face=='L':
                    hero_img = pygame.transform.flip(hero_img, True, False)
                    face='R'
                if herorect.right<size[0]:
                    hero_position[0]+=10

            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                if velocity[1] == 0:
                    gravity=0
                    grav_time=1
                    add_grav_time = True
                    while add_grav_time:
                        gravity += grav_time
                        while gravity <30:
                            velocity[1] -=5
                        while gravity >=30:
                            velocity[1] -=5










                    #gravity = 0 
                    #timer.start()
                    #while gravity <50:
                    #   velocity[1] -=5
                    #   gravity += timer.s()
                    #while gravity >=50:    
                    #   velocity[1] +=5



                    #while velocity[1] >=-10:
                    #   velocity[1] -=5
                    #while velocity[1] <=-10:



        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
            add_time = False
            gravity = 0
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE and velocity[1]<0 :velocity[1] +=10
                        #if event.key==pygame.K_space




                                #Gc=0
                        #elif not keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                                #velocity[1]+=Gc

    herorect.left=hero_position[0]
    herorect.top=hero_position[1]
    if hero_position[1]<0:
        hero_position[1]-=hero_position[1]
    hero_position[0]+=velocity[0]
    hero_position[1]+=velocity[1]
    if herorect.left<0 or herorect.right>=size[0]: velocity[0]=0
    #screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(bkrd,bkrdrect)

    lvl.draw()
    screen.blit(hero_img, herorect)
    pygame.display.flip()

print lvl
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate reason why your program stops is an infinite loop: your `while` condition does not change inside the loop, so the loop never exits once entered.

However, your problem is more conceptual. You cannot do this with a loop inside the game loop: the game loop needs to continue spinning no matter what. In each pass of the game loop you can adjust the velocity a little bit, and do so until the ground is reached (or whatever else condition you have).

If you are modeling real physics, the jump should give you an immediate increase in velocity upwards; then on each pass of the main loop, decrease this velocity by a constant (9.81 m/s/s in real world), and make it zero once you hit ground.

Comment: If I change my code to this gravity works as desired except I can infinitely move up while holding the space bar. is there a way to make it so that velocity moves-5 only once and not forever while the spacebar is held?                                                                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]: 
                if velocity[1] == 0:
                    velocity[1] -=5

Comment: Don't do anything on space unless your character has ground under his feet.